# How to excute a php script in an php extension?

Tags: php

I am writing a PHP extension and I want to load and execute a PHP file in PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION of eht extension. I try to use the embed PHP to load the PHP code, but it triggers a SIGSEGV at the begining of the PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION. The following is the code which I generate by ext_skel and modified some to fit my purpose.

The first key point is in the PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION which I create a embed environment to execute another php code. The second key point is in the config.m4 file which I add the php7 library dependcy. All the comments generated by ext_skel are deleted.

test0.c:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

#include "php.h"
#include "php_ini.h"
#include "ext/standard/info.h"
#include "sapi/embed/php_embed.h"
#include "php_test0.h"

static int le_test0;

PHP_FUNCTION(confirm_test0_compiled)
{
    char *arg = NULL;
    size_t arg_len, len;
    zend_string *strg;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), "s", &arg, &arg_len) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    strg = strpprintf(0, "Congratulations! You have successfully modified ext/%.78s/config.m4. Module %.78s is now compiled into PHP.", "test0", arg);

    RETURN_STR(strg);
}

PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(test0)
{
    php_error_docref(NULL, E_NOTICE, "Moudle test init[%d]", getpid());
    zval retval;
    PHP_EMBED_START_BLOCK(0, NULL)
        zend_eval_string("return 'abcdefg';", &retval, "execution");
    PHP_EMBED_END_BLOCK()
    php_error_docref(NULL, E_NOTICE, "PHP returns:[%s]", Z_STRVAL(retval));
    return SUCCESS;
}

PHP_MSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION(test0)
{
    return SUCCESS;
}

PHP_MINFO_FUNCTION(test0)
{
    php_info_print_table_start();
    php_info_print_table_header(2, "test0 support", "enabled");
    php_info_print_table_end();

    /* Remove comments if you have entries in php.ini
    DISPLAY_INI_ENTRIES();
    */
}

const zend_function_entry test0_functions[] = {
    PHP_FE(confirm_test0_compiled,  NULL)       /* For testing, remove later. */
    PHP_FE_END      /* Must be the last line in test0_functions[] */
};

zend_module_entry test0_module_entry = {
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
    "test0",
    test0_functions,
    PHP_MINIT(test0),
    PHP_MSHUTDOWN(test0),
    NULL,
    NULL,
    PHP_MINFO(test0),
    PHP_TEST0_VERSION,
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

#ifdef COMPILE_DL_TEST0
#ifdef ZTS
ZEND_TSRMLS_CACHE_DEFINE()
#endif
ZEND_GET_MODULE(test0)
#endif
```

config.m4:

```
PHP_ARG_WITH(test0, for test0 support,
Make sure that the comment is aligned:
[  --with-test0             Include test0 support])

if test "$PHP_TEST0" != "no"; then
  LIBNAME=php7
  LIBSYMBOL=php_embed_init

  PHP_CHECK_LIBRARY($LIBNAME,$LIBSYMBOL,
  [
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH($LIBNAME, $TEST0_DIR/$PHP_LIBDIR, TEST0_SHARED_LIBADD)
    AC_DEFINE(HAVE_TEST0LIB,1,[ ])
  ],[
    AC_MSG_ERROR([wrong test0 lib version or lib not found])
  ],[
    -L$TEST0_DIR/$PHP_LIBDIR -lm
  ])

  PHP_SUBST(TEST0_SHARED_LIBADD)
  PHP_REQUIRE_CXX()
  PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(test0, test0.c, $ext_shared,, -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1)
fi
```

Comment: could you share the error you get ?

Comment: I got “segment fault” and a core dump, I use GDB to debug the core file and find the error occure at the first line of PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION

Comment: could you share the whole code ?

Comment: I have add the whole code in the question.